# Angular select list multiple selection with no checkbox not working properly

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

Im doing a list of selectable items and checkbox should not be visibile.

Demo :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-selection-list-get-options-gcsdjd?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.ts

Background field when items selected its not working properly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens in your CSS is that `mat-list-option:hover` and `mat-list-option:focus` styles have higher specificity than your styles,

So whenever your list item is hovered or focused (it happens when you click on the item) you see the styles from `mat-list-option:hover`.

What you need to do is to make specificity of your styles higher, for example:

```
mat-list-option[aria-selected='true'],
mat-list-option[aria-selected='true']:hover,
mat-list-option[aria-selected='true']:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.7);
}
```

Or you can just add an additional class to your list items, and then use it in the CSS:

```
mat-list-option.list-item[aria-selected='true'] {
  background: rgba(0, 139, 139, 0.7);
}
```

And of course you can use `important` modifier as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you don't do nothing in the `onNgModelChange` in which you should update your selected option

Comment: I dont want to do something. I want the style background to work when select an item.

Comment: If you don't write any logic to update the current value, how do you expect to see any change?

Comment: Its written on css